# Estimating resolution interpolated from point samples

Tags: raster, spatial-statistics, resolution, sampling

I have a series of data samples (actually satellite measurements), and I am interpolating the data to produce a raster. I can interpolate to any arbitrary resolution I like; but how can I estimate the effective resolution of the data?

E.g. If my data points are no closer than 100m, I could interpolate to a 10m grid or a 1m grid but it could never reasonably be called anything better than 100 m.

The best approach I have come up with is to create a Delaunay Triangulation and then to run statistics on the edge lengths. This produces something that looks like a Poisson distribution (haven't rigorously checked) with the addition of two spikes. The very long tail appears to be due to edge effects, or the tendency for the Delauney Triangulation to "fill" holes with edges. I think this might over-estimate the mean distance, and gives me concern that it isn't the best approach.

The two spikes were expected and would confirm the approach is broadly working. Being satellite data, the spikes correspond to samples along a sampling track and between sampling tracks (an orbit involves multiple sampling tracks separated by a few hundred metres).

I have seen this question: [Estimating resolution of vector data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/245338/1205) but that is more about vector positioning and comparing against an external dataset.
I am interested in effective spatial sampling resolution.

Is there a better approach than my Delaunay Triangulation stats ?
What is usually used by the national cartographers when produce their elevation models/etc?

Comment: I suppose it depends on data. If you measure mean sea level at 100 m intervals then interpolation to a 10 m grid may be  reasonable because the level is changing smoothly and does not have steep steps, unlike mountainous terrain.